# How to break line into ExPex pack?

Tags: xetex, verse, expex

I want to transliterate a poem from ancient greek and keep the verse layout of the Poem. I tried to use `\usepackage{verse}`, `\\` and `\newline` in the enviroment `\gla`, but did not work, the code does not break the lines into `\gla`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{expex}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter}
 {\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
 {1pc}
 {\vspace{1pc}%
   \LARGE}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
 {\normalfont
  \vspace{0pt}%
   \bfseries\Large\filleft}
{\thesection}{.5em}{} 
\titlespacing{\section}
{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}:\arabic{section}}

\lingset{glhangstyle=none}
\begin{document}

\begingl

\gla ἥκω Διὸς παῖς τήνδε Θηβαίων χθόνα
Διόνυσος, ὃν τίκτει ποθ᾽ ἡ Κάδμου κόρη 
Σεμέλη λοχευθεῖσ᾽ ἀστραπηφόρῳ πυρί:
μορφὴν δ᾽ ἀμείψας ἐκ θεοῦ βροτησίαν
πάρειμι Δίρκης νάματ᾽ Ἰσμηνοῦ θ᾽ ὕδωρ.
ὁρῶ δὲ μητρὸς μνῆμα τῆς κεραυνίας
τόδ᾽ ἐγγὺς οἴκων καὶ δόμων ἐρείπια
τυφόμενα Δίου πυρὸς ἔτι ζῶσαν φλόγα,
ἀθάνατον Ἥρας μητέρ᾽ εἰς ἐμὴν ὕβριν.
10αἰνῶ δὲ Κάδμον, ἄβατον ὃς πέδον τόδε
τίθησι, θυγατρὸς σηκόν: ἀμπέλου δέ νιν
πέριξ ἐγὼ 'κάλυψα βοτρυώδει χλόῃ. //

\glb Chegando Zeus Filho {de onde} Tebas Terra
    Dionísio que //
\endgl


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `expex` package allows you to use `+` in the `gla` line to break lines manually. See section 9.2.1 in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/expex/expex-doc.pdf).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{expex}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter}
 {\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
 {1pc}
 {\vspace{1pc}%
   \LARGE}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
 {\normalfont
  \vspace{0pt}%
   \bfseries\Large\filleft}
{\thesection}{.5em}{} 
\titlespacing{\section}
{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}:\arabic{section}}

\lingset{glhangstyle=none}
\begin{document}

\begingl

\gla ἥκω Διὸς παῖς τήνδε Θηβαίων χθόνα +
Διόνυσος, ὃν τίκτει ποθ᾽ ἡ Κάδμου κόρη +
Σεμέλη λοχευθεῖσ᾽ ἀστραπηφόρῳ πυρί: +
μορφὴν δ᾽ ἀμείψας ἐκ θεοῦ βροτησίαν +
πάρειμι Δίρκης νάματ᾽ Ἰσμηνοῦ θ᾽ ὕδωρ. +
ὁρῶ δὲ μητρὸς μνῆμα τῆς κεραυνίας +
τόδ᾽ ἐγγὺς οἴκων καὶ δόμων ἐρείπια +
τυφόμενα Δίου πυρὸς ἔτι ζῶσαν φλόγα, +
ἀθάνατον Ἥρας μητέρ᾽ εἰς ἐμὴν ὕβριν. +
10αἰνῶ δὲ Κάδμον, ἄβατον ὃς πέδον τόδε +
τίθησι, θυγατρὸς σηκόν: ἀμπέλου δέ νιν +
πέριξ ἐγὼ 'κάλυψα βοτρυώδει χλόῃ. //

\glb Chegando Zeus Filho {de onde} Tebas Terra
    Dionísio que //
\endgl


\end{document}
```

[image]