# coexistence of linguex and expex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics, linguex, expex

I have a very naive question. I started using `linguex` package, but now I realized I need some options that only `expex` has. I was wondering if the two packages be used in the same document, or would they be in conflict with one another.

The reason I ask this, is that I need to do the following with `linguex`, but I am not sure it is doable. First, I need to have right-aligned comments on the first and third line of a gloss.

Based on on the question linked in the comments:

- [Labeling linguistic examples with language information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49579)

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\begin{document}

\ex. \a. The girls kissed the boy \hfill {\small \checkmark X}
\bg. The boy didn't kiss the girl \\ 
D boy AUX.NEG kiss D girl \\ \hfill {\small \checkmark X}
\trans 'The boy did not kiss the girl'. \hfill {\small \checkmark X}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't quite do what I want because ... ?

[image: output of code]

Second, I need to add arrows/lines connecting two parts of the example. Something like: [image: arrows in examples]

Comment: It's not impossible in some cases, but not recommended. What do you need that `linguex` can't do? Maybe that problem can be solved.

Comment: I would need to add right-aligned comments on some lines of glosses. I found a trick by using the command `\raisebox`, but it doesn't work when you need comments on more than one line of a gloss.

Comment: You mean like here: [Labeling linguistic examples with language information](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49579) (this will also work for `linguex` I think.)  I think you should post a minimal example of what you want to do with `linguex` and then we'll see if it can be solved.

Comment: I edited my question accordingly. Hope you guys can help somehow!

Comment: You're using the glossing macros incorrectly. Each gloss line needs to end with \\ and the `\hfill` stuff goes afterward.  Also, `\small` does not take an argument, so you should write `{\small\checkmark}`. The solution I point to in the linked question will solve the gloss problem.  But the second problem is an entirely different one, and shouldn't be part of this question, and is also a duplicate of [Movement arrow in gloss](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140142)

Comment: Thank you for replying, and sorry for mixing topics up. I updated the answer above. Apparently, your solution does word with examples, but not with glosses.

Comment: Your edited question is not the solution given in the linked question. You need to install the `cgloss` package and load that after loading `linguex`.

Comment: I hate hassling, but it still doesn't work - see the follow-up above.

Comment: We can't tell what doesn't work unless you show us exactly what you are doing and what you want. But part of your problem is because you are still not using the glossing macros correctly. Your third line should be introduced by `\trans` or `\glt`. But it's true that you can only put right aligned stuff on the first line or the `\trans` line, but not on the gloss line itself. If you don't mind I'll edit your question to make it clear and then it can be reopened.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question. What I want, is to have the possibility of putting right-aligned comments on both the first and third lines in a gloss. I also tried to but `\glt` or `\trans`, but right commenting still get mixed up with the actual gloss.

I really feel like I should convert the entire document according to the `expex` macro.

Comment: I've edited the question using code from the linked answer. Does this do what you want or do you also want right aligned comments somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you, Alan! That is definitely helpful! What if I want to do a comment on the second line?

Comment: Before you ask for that, ask yourself if you *really* need it. The first and second lines of a glossed example are logically one line so it's not clear that you would ever need to have comments on the gloss line itself. As it currently stands, you can't add a comment there. But remember 'what if' question is asking others to spend time solving the problem for you (as this comment thread attests to) and unless you have a demonstrated need for this, I would just stick with what you can do simply.

Comment: One other comment: it's clear from the way your code samples went that you didn't understand how the glossing macros work. Partially this is because the `linguex` documentation of that is not so clear. You might want to take a look at the `gb4e` documentation which discusses the glossing macros more explicitly.  This is *not* a suggestion to switch to `gb4e` (although personally I prefer it) but just a suggestion to read its documentation for the glossing macros.

Comment: Fair enough - I just started using LaTeX, so yes - I think I'm still confused about how glossing works with `gb4e`. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: If you really want to have a right-aligned comment on the second (gloss) line, the `expex` command `\rightcomment` works. You can just take the first example in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211489/42880) and move the `\rightcomment` from the `\gla` to the `\glb` line. Beware that this command may result in overlapping text and would then require [manual line breaking](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318125/42880). However, I agree with @AlanMunn that this would have limited usage in practice, and I'm not recommending that you switch to `expex` just for this feature.

Comment: @JasonZentz Can you email me. I've cooked up something that it would be nice to have and ExPex user test.